# Split cell in jupyter/ipython not working

Tags: ipython

I've tried to use the command for spliting  cell 'm -' but it doesn't work. All the reset of the key commands work fine with either esc or fn key as modifiers. I'm also in the correct mode(edititng mode).

Answer (score 3):

Splitting cell is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (minus sign) in edit mode.

Comment: @idnavid, I've approved your edit, but note that you can use HTML entity `<kbd>` to format keys.